# How to throw and get the exception object in MoQ WebAPI

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata, moq, exceptionhandler

I have an OData enabled WebAPI that contains

1. TestController: It contains a single custom action method.
2. WebApiExceptionHandler: Custom exception handler in WebApi,
   registered in WebApiConfig.cs.
3. ITestManager: Interface
4. TestManager: Class implementing the ITestManager. This class handles
   all the business logic for data. WebAPI controller TestController
   has a single function that calls this class.

   Also, there is a TestWebAPI Project which uses MoQ framework for testing. The TestMethod "Test_UpdatePackageVendorOnException__Success" uses MoQ setup to throw Exception in UpdateTestQuantity method. But when I debug this test method, when the exception is thrown, the debugger does not point in the WebApiExceptionHandler class. Ideally all exceptions occurring in the API are handled in the WebApiExceptionHandler class

The problem I am facing is that in my test method, I want to test something on the exception object returned by the WebApiExceptionHandler. But since the control is never going in the WebApiExceptionHandler, so I can't do that.

How can I modify the code so that in the TestMethod I can test the custom object returned by the WebApiExceptionHandler.

WebAPI Code:

```
    public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Services.Replace(typeof(IExceptionHandler), new WebApiExceptionHandler());

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
          name: "DefaultApiGetParam",
          routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{key}/{count}",
          defaults: new { key = RouteParameter.Optional, count = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}

public class WebApiExceptionHandler : ExceptionHandler
{
    public WebApiExceptionHandler()
    {
    }
    public override void Handle(ExceptionHandlerContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            var objCustomException = new CustomException(context.Exception);
            context.Result = new ResponseMessageResult(context.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, objCustomException);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            base.Handle(context);
        }
    }

    public override bool ShouldHandle(ExceptionHandlerContext context)
    {
        return true;
    }
}


public interface ITestManager
{
    bool UpdateTestQuantity();

}

public class TestManager : ITestManager
{
    public TestManager()
    {
    }


    public bool UpdateTestQuantity()
    {
        //Custom Logic
        return true;
    }
}

public class TestController : ODataController
{
    ITestManager testManager;

    public TestController()
    {
        testManager = new TestManager();
    }

    public TestController(ITestManager iTestManager)
    {
        testManager = iTestManager;
    }

    public IHttpActionResult UpdateTestQuantity(ODataActionParameters param)
    {
        bool result = testManager.UpdateTestQuantity();
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

WebApiTest Project

```
[TestClass]
public class TestControllerTest
{

    Mock<ITestManager> iTestManagerMock;
    TestController objTestController;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void Setup()
    {
        iTestManagerMock = new Mock<ITestManager>();
    }

    [TestMethod]
    [ExpectedException(typeof(Exception), AllowDerivedTypes = true)]
    public void Test_UpdateTestQuantityOnException__Success()
    {
        iTestManagerMock.Setup(i => i.UpdateTestQuantity().Throws(new Exception());
        objTestController = new TestController(iTestManagerMock.Object);
        var objODataActionParameters = new ODataActionParameters();
        objTestController.Request = new HttpRequestMessage();
        objTestController.Configuration = new HttpConfiguration();
        IHttpActionResult objIHttpActionResult = objTestController.UpdateTestQuantity(objODataActionParameters);

        //Problem Area
        //Control never reaches here after the exception is thrown  
        //Want to check some property of exception object returned via Exception WebApiExceptionHandler 
    }

    [TestCleanup]
    public void Clean()
    {
        iTestManagerMock = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: There are way to many unnecessary info provided. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: This would require an integration test where all the moving parts are configured, not a unit test like what you currently are trying to implement

Comment: @SergeyShushlyapin My bad that I provided lots of information. Your point duly noted.

Comment: @Nkosi how can I then unit test the ExceptionHandler in WebAPI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `[ExpectedException]` test method attribute (which violates the [AAA](http://wiki.c2.com/?ArrangeActAssert) principle) and rewrite the *assert* section of your test to use the [`Assert.Throws`](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Assert.Throws) NUnit method.

Comment: Using NUnit works like charm. But I am still stuck with one problem. What my am finding hard to understand is that fact that I have used ExceptionHandler to handle all exceptions in API. When I use MoQ "iTestManagerMock.Setup(i => i.UpdateTestQuantity().Throws(new Exception()); to throw exception explicitly, then why does the control never reaches ExceptionHandler class that returns the Exception object. In my Test method, I need to see that object returned by ExceptionHandler to do Assert.